# How can I "match" an array to tableview cells / rows

Tags: ios

I have an app with a tableView that displays various UI elements with information about vitamins.  The order is user dependent and stored in an array. 
I currently display the correct information using a huge number of if statements, like so:

```
//IndexPath == 0
if indexPath.row == 0 && vitmaminsArray[0] == "A" {
    title.text = "Vitamin A"
    vitaminAinfo()
    …
}

if indexPath.row == 0 && vitmaminsArray[0] == "B" {
    title.text = "Vitamin B"
    vitaminBinfo()
    …
}

if indexPath.row == 0 && vitmaminsArray[0] == "C" {
    title.text = "Vitamin C"
    vitaminCinfo()
    …
}

etc 

//IndexPath == 1
if indexPath.row == 1 && vitmaminsArray[1] == "A" {
    title.text = "Vitamin A"
    vitaminAinfo()
    …
}

if indexPath.row == 1 && vitmaminsArray[1] == "B" {
    title.text = "Vitamin B"
    vitaminBinfo()
    …
}

if indexPath.row == 1 && vitmaminsArray[1] == "C" {
    title.text = "Vitamin C"
    vitaminCinfo()
    …
}

etc
```

I think this is a really dumb solution, but I don't know of a better way to "map" tableView Cells with the corresponding content.  If it was just the title I could write

```
title.text = vitmaminsArray[indexPath.row]
```

but it is much more than that. Any help would be much appreciated - Thank you !

Comment: Can you please post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath? I don't understand how just getting the object in the array for the index path would not solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another level of indirection:

```
title.text = vitmaminsArray[userIndexForItem[indexPath.row]]
```

Where the userIndexForItem[] array maps the user-specific index to the main index.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some more code/example and explain?

Comment: You store a single array of vitamin info, then for every user you use an array whose values are indices into the first array. That is, the order of your vitamins in the first array is always the same, but in the second array, you get to "shuffle" them whichever way you want while keeping a reference to the vitamin entry in the original vitamin array.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, very neat and it solved my problem. example:  line1: var vitamins = ["A", "B", "C"]
line2: var userIndexForItem = [3,2,1]
line3: var pickedarray = vitamins[userIndexForItem[1]] line4 log: C

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of objects, have vitaminInfo take an object:

```
//or not void if you need a return
-(void)vitaminInfo:(Vitamin *)vitamin
{
   do stuff with vitamin
}
```

in cellForRow

```
Vitamin *vitamin = [vitaminArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.title.text = vitamin.name;
[self vitaminInfo:vitamin];
```

Comment: Because I am not just setting the title.  I need to evaluate various functions as well and they are different for each vitamin.  I need to fill cell at indexpath.row with content that depends on the order in vitaminsArray.  VitmainsArray may be [A, C, E, D] or just [D].  If just [D] I need to fill the first cell with info related to Vitamin D, that info is not just the title, but also computed properties in vitaminDinfo().

Comment: Can you please post a complete example of what it is supposed to look like? Where are you storing the vitaminDInfo?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is 2000 lines long - I can't post all that, sorry.  It contains vitaminAinfo(), vitaminBinfo(), vitaminCinfo() etc.

Comment: I am basically trying to untangle it.

Comment: What is in vitaminCInfo and how are you associating it to "C" in the vitaminsArray?

Comment: I am associating it with this line: if indexPath.row == 1 && vitmaminsArray[1] == "C".  If it evaluates as true, vitaminCinfo() is evaluated, the title is set, icons are set etc.  vitaminCinfo() creates a chart that shows how much vitamin C you have consumed.

Comment: @karlml If your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is 2000 lines long then you're doing something seriously wrong. What is the structure of your data?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. What is your data structure? Is vitaminXInfo() referencing a separate array? A Dictionary? Is vitaminsArray only containing the "X" letter?

Comment: I know it is bad code, yesterday @rdelmar kindly showed me how to slim it down by a few hundred lines :-)  vitaminCinfo() creates a chart that shows how much vitamin C you have consumed

Comment: And all that information is put back in the cell? Basically you just need to know which method to call in based on the letter in the vitaminsArray? Does vitaminCInfo() get it's data from a dictionary or something?

Comment: @karlml, your data structure should probably be an array of custom Vitamin objects. These objects would have as many properties as you need to display in your various UI elements. One property would be name, then you could set the title with cell.title.text = (vitaminArray[indexPath.row] as Vitamin).name

Comment: I agree with @rdelmar.

Comment: @Siriss Yes. But it is also minerals, proteins etc, but that is unimportant I guess.  vitaminCinfo gets its data from HealthKit.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes - I am trying to implement a solution like that.  However, it still leaves open the question how to map each cell/row with the correct info.

Comment: I updated my answer to sort of point you in the right direction.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you both for very useful advice and constructive feedback.  Now I know what must be my priority, chopping up this code and refactoring.  I love coding, I learn many new concepts and techniques every day - thank you for helping me on my journey from a trader to a self/stackoverflow/udemy-taught coder !